# Find UIViewController registered or not for 3D Touch support

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, 3dtouch

How to know that UIViewController is already registered or not to support 3D touch preview (peek) and commit (pop)

Following method registers

```
UIViewController:
 (id <UIViewControllerPreviewing>)registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:(id<UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate>)delegate sourceView:(UIView *)sourceView
```

If we register view controller multiple times then corresponding delegate method `(UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate)` gets called multiple times.

Comment: I am not sure but can't you do it by implementing a check
`if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(methodName:)])`
 will return true if proper delegate has been set. "methodName" can be any method in your respective protocol.

Comment: @Shehzad Ali: This will return true even if I have implemented the delegate method and not registered the view controller for 3D touch support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are registering the same view more than once. You can do something like the following in viewDidLoad to ensure one time call for registerForPreviewingWithDelegate method

```
// Register for 3D Touch Previewing if available
if ([self.traitCollection respondsToSelector:@selector(forceTouchCapability)] &&
        (self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable))
{
    [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:self.view];
}
```

Although it is managed by OS itself, if you want to unregister the view for peek and pop, you can call the **unregisterForPreviewingWithContext**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/unregisterForPreviewingWithContext:

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case, I have the reference of `UIViewController` class object and I need to add 3D Touch support to it from outside of this class object if it's already not supporting.

Comment: Did you try calling unregisterForPreviewingWithContext first and then register?